# Why is HHVM is slower than PHP-FPM with Dynamodb Calls

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, hhvm

I am evaluating HHVM, it seems to be way slower than PHP-FPM (with opcache).

This is profiling result of HHVM
http://ldr.io/1nobQyT

This is profiling result of PHP-FPM
http://ldr.io/SzSQmW

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything wrong with the HHVM configuration?

Here is the test script I am running

```
include 'aws_sdk2/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\DynamoDb\Crc32ErrorChecker;
use Aws\Common\Client\ThrottlingErrorChecker;
use Aws\Common\Enum\ClientOptions;
use Aws\Common\Exception\Parser\JsonQueryExceptionParser;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\BackoffPlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\CallbackBackoffStrategy;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\CurlBackoffStrategy;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\HttpBackoffStrategy;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\TruncatedBackoffStrategy;

echo Aws\Common\Enum\Region::NORTHERN_VIRGINIA;

 $config = array (
    'key'    => '',
    'secret' => '',
    'region' => Aws\Common\Enum\Region::NORTHERN_VIRGINIA,
    'scheme' => 'http',
);

 $query = array (
      'TableName' => 'dev_session_sv1',
      'Key' =>
      array (
        'id' =>
        array (
          'N' => '72',
        ),
      ),
      'ConsistentRead' => true,
    );


$a = Aws\Common\Aws::factory($config);
$db = $a->get('DynamoDb');
$result = $db->describeTable(array(
    'TableName' => 'dev_rishabh_sv1'
));
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $result->getPath('Table/ProvisionedThroughput/ReadCapacityUnits');
```

**Here is the HHVM configuration**

```
Server {
  Port = 9000
  Type = fastcgi
  SourceRoot = /home/ftpcmbin/cm/programs/liger/repo/current/src/htdocs
  DefaultDocument = index.php
  ThreadCount = 15
  APC {
    EnableApc = true
  }
}

Eval {
  Jit = true
  EnableObjDestructCall = true
}
Log {
  Level = Warning
  UseLogFile = true
  File = /var/log/cm/logs/hhvm/error.log
  InjectedStackTrace = true
  NativeStackTrace = true
  NoSilencer = on
  Header = on
  Access {
    * {
      File = /var/log/cm/logs/hhvm/access.log
      Format = %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b
    }
  }
}

VirtualHost {
  * {
    Pattern = .*
    RewriteRules {
      dirindex {
        pattern = ^/(.*)/$
        to = $1/index.php
        qsa = true
      }
    }
  }
}
StaticFile {
  FilesMatch {
    * {
      pattern = .*\.(dll|exe)
      headers {
        * = Content-Disposition: attachment
      }
    }
  }
  Extensions {
    css = text/css
    gif = image/gif
    html = text/html
    jpe = image/jpeg
    jpeg = image/jpeg
    jpg = image/jpeg
    png = image/png
    tif = image/tiff
    tiff = image/tiff
    txt = text/plain
  }
}
ResourceLimit {
    CoreFileSize = 0          # in bytes
    MaxSocket = 50000         # must be not 0, otherwise HHVM will not start
    SocketDefaultTimeout = 5  # in seconds
    MaxRSS = 0
    MaxRSSPollingCycle = 0    # in seconds, how often to check max memory
    DropCacheCycle = 60        # in seconds, how often to drop disk cache
}
```

Comment: And... what is your question?

Comment: Are you just looking at requests, or are you actually doing profiling on the calls? Measure the time taken for each call and loop for a large number (e.g. 100000000) of times, and see if that is the case. before running, make sure you run hhvm for at least about 20 times (with a small number of calls as well), as JIT only comes into effect after about 12 calls if I am not mistaken.

Comment: As others have said, make sure you're doing enough work to overcome the warmup period; HHVM can be slower to start up and get warmed up than stock PHP. Also get as much code out of the toplevel ("pseudomain") as possible -- wrapping the code you have into a "main" function and calling that enables many optimizations that HHVM simply can't do at the toplevel. Finally make sure your benchmark is actually CPU bound and not spending all its time waiting on AWS or something.